# Remove mysql database record with a button

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I have made a database in Mysql. This database has 3 tables, 1: user 2: activity 3: user_activity. 
user_activity is an koppeltabel (I don't know if this word is proper English, so it's a table that connects the tables user and activity), this table has the rows: 1: ActivityID and UserID.

I have made a script gets content from the database en displays that content (the content is called an activity in my script). Every ativity has his own button and when you push that button, you add that specific activity to your "guide". When you have added an activity to your guide, this activity will also be displayed.

So this is my code so far.
the js script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".addActivity").click( function() {

    var activityId = $(this).data('activity');  

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "add_activity.php",
        data: {
            activity: activityId
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {

        }
    });
    $(this).hide();
    }); 
});
```

And this is my "add_activity.php file:

```
<?php
include "connection.php";

// Haal eerst de gebruikers info van de gebruiker die ingelogd is op
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE Username = '".$_SESSION['Username']."' ";
$stm = $db->prepare($sql);
$result = $stm->execute(array());
while($row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$userID = $row['UserID'];
}

// Lees de activity van $_POST
$activityID = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'activity', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array('min_range' => 1));
if( $activityID )
{
    // Check of the activity bestaat in de database
    $activityQuery = $db->prepare("SELECT ActivityID FROM activity LIMIT 1");
    $activityQuery->execute( array( $activityID ) );
    if( 1 === $activityQuery->rowCount() )
    {
        // Voeg het record toe
        $activityQuery = $db->prepare("REPLACE INTO user_activity(`UserID`,`ActivityID`)VALUES (?, ?)");
        $activityQuery->execute( array( $userID, $activityID ) );
        if( 0 < $activityQuery->rowCount() )
        {
            echo "Record toegevoegd.";
            exit;
        }
    }
}

// Failure
echo "Er is een fout opgetreden.";
?>
```

and this is my button:

```
echo '<input type="button" class="addActivity" onclick="MakeRequest(' . $test . ')" value="Activiteit toevoegen" data-activity="' . $row['ActivityID'] . '">';
```

This script creats a new record in user_activity,
but now i also want to have a button that deletes a record from user_activity. 
I have tried to modifie this script, but I had no succes.
I hope you have enough information, and that there is someone who is willing to help me.

Comment: What is it exactly that is not working?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a `delete_activity.php` file and run a query like:

```
DELETE FROM `user_activity` ...
```

then just make a similar AJAX call to another button:

```
$(".delActivity").click( function() {

    var activityId = $(this).data('activity');  

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "delete_activity.php",
        data: {
            activity: activityId
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
        }
    });

    $(this).hide();
    }); 

});
```

Comment: @akehorn, what does it mean exactly "with no success"?